# Next,js 13 server component and rerender fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

For example I want toggle url from getData function. I have my main page component with json todos. Can I replace 'todos' with 'users' by my client component?

```
import styles from './page.module.css'
import Button from "@/components/Button";

async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }

  return res.json();
}

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await getData();
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <div>
      {data.map(item => {
        return item.id
      })}
      </div>
      <Button />
    </main>
  )
```

There my button. I don't fully understand how I can change my url for rerender in server. Example I click my button and "todos" changed too "users". If you can write some examples.

```
'use client'
export default function Button(props){
    props.getData('users')

    return(
        <button>3</button>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

You need to add a param to the `getData` to accept the route.

```
async function getData(route) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${route}`);
...
```

Then on the initial load, pass in "todos"

```
const data = await getData("todos");
...
```

You will need to pass in the func `getData` to the button then call it.

```
   <Button getData={getData} />
```

However, personally I wouldn't do this, I would create a new route `/user/[id].tsx`, then query the specific users you clicked on in that component. This is called dynamic routing, see [Next13 docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#example)

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm new on Next.js. And I don't know where to start, pages with getServerSideProps or start with new beta features.